# mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given when querying 2 tables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ok, so I don't know if this can be done, but I need to combine the results of 2 Where clauses from 2 tables into one variable.

So far I have this working to query one table:

```php
$allCompanies = Products::where('category_id', $id->id)->groupBy('company_id')->get();
```

And this for the other:

```php
$companies = Company::where('visible', 0)->get();
```

But is there any way to get them into the same query string? Something like so I can get where the ID matches the ID column in one table AND where visible is 0 in the other?

I tried this:

```php
$allCompanies = Products::with('company', function($q){
            $q->where('visible', 0);
            })->where('category_id', $id->id)
            ->groupBy('company_id')->get();
```

but got this error:

```
mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Company Model:

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Company extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Products');
    }
}
```

Products Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Products extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description',
        'image',
        'size',
        'price',
        'stock',
        'company_id',
        'category_id'
    ];
    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories', 'category_id');
    }
    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

When using callback in `with`, you should pass callback as value of associative-array.

Your query should be:

```
$allCompanies = Products::with(['company' => function($q) {
    $q->where('visible', 0);
}])
    ->where('category_id', $id->id)
    ->groupBy('company_id')
    ->get();
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading-morphto-relationships

Answer (score 2):

The most Laravel way of achieving this is through [`Relationships`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) and [`whereHas`](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence). If you have a relationship defined you could do the following:

```php
$products = Products::where('category_id', $id->id)
                        ->whereHas('company', function($q) {
                          $q->where('visible', 0);
                        });
```

Which will query for all the products with a certain `category_id` that also have a relationship with a company that has a column `visible` with value 0

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want:

If you want all the products from visible companies:

```
$products = Products::whereHas('company', function($q) {
   $q->where('visible',0);
})->get();
```

If you want all the companies with their products (which I would advise):

```
$Companies = Company::with('products')->where('visible',0)->get();
```

Comment: Sadly this brought back no results, when there should be

Comment: If you change the `->get()` to `->toSql()` you can see what SQL is run, which could be easier to debug.

Comment: I get ```"select * from `products` where exists (select * from `companies` where `products`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` and `visible` = ?)"```

Comment: I would advise running that straight on the database and tweak that query to get what you want and see what is going on. Does the subquery (select * from `companies` where `visible` = 0)  return the right companies? Are their products attached to the companies?

Comment: Hmm ok so it runs, I can see a difference as I can change the 'visible' query to 1 or 0 and it shows different returns, but for some reason I see each company repeated dozens and dozens of times.

Comment: Actually when I add toSql(), I get the error ```Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\EdenBeauty\resources\views\allCategories.blade.php)``` That part in the blade reads ```<p class="text-center navLinksViewProduct">
        @foreach($allCompanies as $company) <a href="#{{ $company->company->company }}">{{ $company->company->company }}
            @if(!$loop->last)
                |
            @endif
        </a>
       @endforeach
    </p>```

Comment: Yeah, that toSql() part was for debugging (it just returns the string. I find it hard to pinpoint exactly where your error originates from. Maybe with the models I can figure it out better. Could you add them to your post?

Comment: Ok added the models in now

Comment: Nice, can you also add how you would like your data to be returned? Like what structure do you want your data to have?

Comment: I'd like to turn the results into an array so I can loop through it in the blade view